# Pass data between Node.js and Html

Tags: html, node.js

How can I pass the "term" variable from the html site to the node.js?

**My HTML Page : search.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input id="begriff" type="name" name="" value="">

    <button style="margin-top: 50px;" onclick="information()" >send</button>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var term;

    function information() {
        term    = document.getElementById("name").value;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Node.JS  : app.js**
I want to search with the 'term' variable for apps in the Playstore and give the information back to the html and print it there somewhere.

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.search({
    term: "Html 'Term' variable",
    num: 1,
    fullDetail: false,
    price: "free"
}).then(console.log, console.log);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is set up a server that will take a request, perform the search, and send back the results. [Express](https://expressjs.com) is a popular framework for doing this.

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    // This will run every time you send a request to localhost:3000/search
    var term = req.params.term;
    gplay.search({
        term: term,
        num: 1,
        fullDetail: false,
        price: "free"
    }).then(function(result) {
        // Process the result however you want.
        // To send a response back, do this:
        res.send("Whatever you want to send back");
    });
})

// Tell Express what port to listen on
app.listen(3000);
```

While your Node.js program is running, JavaScript code in your HTML page can use the `fetch` function to send it a request and get back the response.

```
function information() {
    var term = document.getElementById("begriff").value; // The id of your input was "begriff", not "name"
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/search?term=' + term;
    // Now send a request to your Node program
    fetch(url).then(function(res) {
        // Res will be a Response object.
        // Use res.text() or res.json() to get the information that the Node program sent.
    });
}
```

Once you have your [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, you can process the information it contains and display it in the page.